# charting with SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, reporting-services, charts

I am trying to create a line chart within a C# WPF application.
I have searched far and wide for an answer to my question. I know this is a long shot but 
I am desperate. The SQL query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT stock_symbol, stock_date, stock_price_adj_close 
FROM MoneyBMine.dbo.NYSE 
WHERE stock_symbol IN ('AA', 'AIT') 
AND stock_date BETWEEN '2000-01-03' AND '2000-02-04'
```

OR:

```sql
SELECT stock_symbol, stock_date, stock_price_adj_close 
FROM MoneyBMine.dbo.NYSE 
WHERE stock_symbol = 'AA' 
AND stock_date BETWEEN '2000-01-03' AND '2000-02-04'
```

I am just trying to get any of my values to be displayed on a chart inside my application.
I have also tried ReportViewer and making reports in "Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder" but again, trying to bring these reports into my C# WPF application nothing is working. So what I am asking is a way to visualise SQL data on some sort of chart/report in a C# WPF application.

Comment: Once you get the values in C# I guess you can draw a line graph by manually drawing it to a WPF canvas. Did I understand your question correctly here??

Comment: If using an external library is no problem for you, take a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714591.aspx

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using OxyPlot, you can get it [here](https://oxyplot.codeplex.com/) ... It's much nicer and easier to work with than WPF own solution (the charting dll they supply has NO documentation).

once you have it, in your code you can do:

```
// Create plot
var plot_model = new PlotModel()  { Title = title};

// Create points
var points = from_a_method_linq_Sql_whatever();
var line_series = new LineSeries();

// Add plot to serie
foreach (var point in points)
    line_series.Points.Add(point);

// Add them to the plot
plot_model.Series.Add(line_series);
```

I would have this plot as a property, and then simply bind to it from the XAML like this:

```
<oxy:Plot Model="{Binding OutputChart}" />
```

(make sure you have this on top of your xaml:

```
 xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Wpf;assembly=OxyPlot.Wpf"
```

You can also have your points exposed as a property and do all from the binding on the xaml. Your choice.

Adding axis and legends is simple as, just have a quick look at their documentation / forum.

**Edit:**
I've used something like this in an application I wrote:

```
// Running on a collection of objects that have dates and levels, and other things
foreach (var obj in lvl_reps)
{
    points.Add(new ExercisePoint
    {
        DateTime = exercise.Date,
        Lvl = obj.Level,
        X = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(exercise.Date.AddHours(-12)),
        Y = obj.Reps.Sum(),
        Exercise = exercise.Exercise
    });
}
```

Don't let ExercisePoint scare you, here's the implementation of it:

```
/// <summary>
/// Extends the normal point used by OxyPlot to include the level and the date.
/// The Idea is to use them on the tool tip of the exercise
/// </summary>
class ExercisePoint : IDataPoint
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public int Lvl { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Exercise { get; set; }
}
```

So this is how you can bind custom fields to points for example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have not used Linq to SQL yet in my studies.
could you please give me some help with writing the code?
Many thanks

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, nor what your query is. Your original question was how to display your data on a chart.

Comment: this is what I'm using as my Linq code:
                var points = from n in nyse
                              where n.stock_symbol == "AA" && n.stock_symbol == "AIT" 
                               select new { n.stock_symbol, n.stock_date, n.stock_price_adj_close };

Comment: ok, so that will give you a collection of objects. what's the question?

Comment: I need n.stock_date on the x axis & n.stock_price_adj_close. not too sure what I am missing.
Thanks

Comment: When you get the objects from the query, just create a point with those values then. I'll update my answer with a small example I've used